# Improving Galaxy Nexus's audio quality

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I found out about this website through androidguys.com and I'm giving it a first shot. :)

I remember when I had my Fascinate which is Samsung Galaxy S, I had Voodoo Sound Control app which helped to improve the sound quality tremendously. So you can imagine my surprise that when I got my Galaxy Nexus(Verizon), the app wasn't supporting it.

My question is, will we ever get Voodoo Control support? It's been awhile since the phone came out but the app didn't get updated yet. This led me to assume that it's either impossible or the developer dropped its support. If it will not get Voodoo Control, what other choices are there?

I'm currently using Volume+ and have tried PowerAMP, Neutron, and PlayerPro. All these do are some EQ and volume increase. They have nothing to do with hardware level sound modification.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Voodoo Sound Control on your Fascinate/SGS worked because of three different pieces - the preinstalled Voodoo Control app, a [specific digital to audio controller](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-nexus/451683-audiophiles-galaxy-nexus-sound-quality-vs-galaxy-s.html), and a kernel that can allow the two to communicate. As best I can tell the Galaxy Nexus doesn't have the correct DAC nor a kernal that would allow the controller app to work. Sorry, it seems you're stuck with EQ apps for sound quality.

My suggestion at this point, if you're needing more volume from your phone, would be to look into external powered amps.